# When using a DB in android are the result sets cached in memory?

Tags: java, android, performance, sqlite

I have a question about using a database in Android.
In Android when using a db we are supposed to use sqlite3 which is an in-memory database right?
I am confused on the following:
Does it make a difference to load e.g. a data set and do a check in-memory with a loop which rows of the result set match a certain criteria vs creating an SQL query with a where clause for that same criteria?
If the database is loaded in-memory it shouldn't matter right?
Am I misunderstanding something here?

Comment: SQLite is not in-memory. Though it could be used as such https://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html

Comment: Most of the point of a database is persistence. Also [don't do data filtering in your code when it's easier to do in a query](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/171024/never-do-in-code-what-you-can-get-the-sql-server-to-do-well-for-you-is-this/171033).

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo:Your post is about when we have a remote server. But in android the processing is done in the device. So there should be no difference. The client has the overhead

Comment: @Jim A `WHERE` clause can use indexes. Your hand-coded filter cannot. A `WHERE` clause will also not load every single row into memory if it doesn't need to.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo:This is also a part I am unclear about. Does the index in SD in android device help the same as when using an index for a HD?